# Let $\mathrm P$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix such that $\mathrm P^{102}= \mathrm O$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Can someone guide me how to deal with these problems. Is there an organised way to proceed in solving these type of questions . Thank you. 
[image]

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix). I think it is going to be sufficiently helpful.

Comment: Thank you @thanasissdr I didn't knew that was a property. This was really helpfull

Comment: Thanks @ekkilop for ur reply . Surely looking forward to Google it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that $0$ is the only eigenvalue. Since zero is the only eigenvalue, you can show it is similar to the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

for some $x$.

From here you can look at each of those cases.